# вытянуть из массива все совпадения js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

есть есть блок .short-description в котором вот такой текст:

```
Мидии, сливочный сыр, твердые сорта сыров, кунжут, соус «майонезно-чесночный», рис.
```

ПРоблема в том что, у меня поиск из этого текста не возможно вытянуть сыр, потому что делал разбиение на запятые, возможно как то регуляркой можно решить этот вопрос (не очень силен в них)? ВОт код:

```
const founds = [...document.querySelectorAll(".short-description")]
  .map((domItem) => [
    domItem,
    domItem.innerText
      .toLowerCase()
      .split(",")
      .map((el) => el.trim())
  ])
  .filter(([_, item]) => {
    for (items of array_f) {
      if (item.includes(items.toLowerCase().trim())) {
        return items;
      }
    }
  })
  .map(([item]) => item.closest('.product'));
  console.log(founds);
  founds.forEach(el => document.querySelector('.filter-result').append(el));
    }
```

Comment: Что бы найти все слова с подстрокой `сыр`, нужен вот такой паттерн: `сыр[а-я]+` - это если подстрока встречается только вначале слов и содержит только кирилические буквы.

Answer (score 0):

```
const str = "Мидии, сливочный сыр, твердые сорта сыров, кунжут, соус «майонезно-чесночный», рис";
const array = str.split(",");
const result = array.map(elem => elem.trim().toLowerCase()).filter(elem => elem.contains('сыр');
```

В результате: `["сливочный сыр", "твердые сорта сыров"]`

Comment: if (item.includes(items.toLowerCase().trim().filter(elem => elem.contains(items)))) в моем случае вот так? array_f - у меня массив такого вида [сыр, авокадо, рис]

Comment: @ilyaaa521, в вашем случае что такое `items`  и `item`?

Comment: items - это элемент массива, в данном случае сыр

Comment: @ilyaaa521, item?